# C# Inputbox string value

Tags: c#, inputbox

I'm creating a login that saves data on a database.

How do I declare the Name entered to the string value as name so when I say .Show it returns the name I typed in?

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title",Name, 0, 0);
    MessageBox.Show(Name);
}
```

Comment: rename `input` to `output`, then `MessageBox.Show(output);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy as this:

Change

```
MessageBox.Show(Name);
```

to

```
MessageBox.Show(input);
```