# How to insert values to MS Access Database without the use of a form in C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm trying to insert values to MS Access Database tables. However, I'm getting really old resources on the web and the only way I see this be done is by creating a form on Visual Studios and using that form to send data.

I'm trying to send data to MS Access without the need of using a form and just straight from the Program.cs.

Is there a way to get this done?

**Code Snippet where I'm trying to add values into the Bill Table:**

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Bills(BillDate,BillNumber)Values('" + 10 + "', '" + 20 + "')";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

**BillTable from MS Access**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCdqk.png)

**Error 1:**

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Is this a console C# application?

Comment: Where should data come from - user input? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176994/c-sharp-inputbox-string-value

Comment: Yes this is a console application. I'm having a hard time understanding the Oledb Class Library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the line that says "cmd.CommandText". I think I'm using the wrong function to insert values to my MS Access.mdb

Comment: What error do you get with the code above? There is an error message? an exception? Please give more details about your problem. For example, what datatype are the two columns BillDate,BillNumber on the access database?

Comment: And the data comes from a file I parsed into sections. I created a Dictionary to store a key and value. I just need to place the value inside of the Access Database

Comment: @Steve I'm not getting any error. The code compiles. However, the data I'm sending it is not sending it to the Bill Table. The BillDate and BillNumber are strings (for now).

Comment: I suspect your connectionstring is not referencing the database that you are looking at. Can you add the connectionstring text in your question?

Comment: @Steve Hmmm... I updated my connectionString again just to see if you were right. And now I'm getting an error. The error will be listed as **Error 1** on my post.

Comment: Now we have something. Cannot insert that data (strings) in the database fields. They are not strings. Again double check what database are you looking at. It is pretty common to fail on this expecially with desktop application that use the DataDirectory shortcut in their connection string

Comment: @Steve do you happen to know how I can check what the datatype is inside of the database I'm working with? The database was given to me.

Comment: Open the db with access, right click on the table name and then choose "Show Structure" (not sure about the exact wording because I have a non english version of access) It is the second menu from top

Comment: @Steve I got it! It's called "Design View". Thank you so much Steve for your help! I think I can figure it out from here!

Comment: I suspect your  BillDate or BillNumber field in the database is of integer type. If it is, you don't need to use quotes around the value.